# Help verifying $\lim \frac{2n^2}{n^3 +3} = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

I am having difficulty with verifying the following using the definition of convergence of a sequence(i.e. a sequence converges to $x$, if  $n \ge N$ $\Longrightarrow$ $|x-x_n|< \epsilon$ )

$$\lim \frac{2n^2}{n^3 +3} = 0$$

Now if I take $$\left|\frac{2n^2}{n^3 +3} - 0\right|< \epsilon$$

I get stuck at $$\frac{n^2}{n^3 +3}< \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$
If I am not wrong we have to show $n>A \epsilon$ for some expression $A$
 and merely writing $$n<\frac{\sqrt \epsilon \sqrt {n^3 +3}} {2}$$ would be incorrect right because we have to show\write $\epsilon$ independently of $n$?

I am having the same difficulty simplifying the relationship between $\epsilon$ and $n$ in the following expression

$$\left|\frac{\sin (n^2)}{\sqrt[3] n}- 0\right| < \epsilon$$

Can anyone give me a hint for these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$ \frac{2n^2}{n^3 +3}
\lt  \frac{2n^2}{n^3}
=\frac{2}{n}
$.

Therefore,
if
$\frac{2}{n}
\lt \epsilon
$
then
$ \frac{2n^2}{n^3 +3}
\lt \epsilon
$.

You don't have to
get the best $n$ -
a fairliy good one
is enough to
prove convergence.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**
$$
0\le\left\lvert\frac{\sin (n^2)}{n^{1/3}}\right\rvert\leq \frac{1}{n^{1/3}}
$$
and
$$
0\le\frac{2n^2}{n^3+3}\leq 2\frac{n^2}{n^3}=\frac{2}{n}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

For $n > \frac2{\varepsilon}$ we have

$$\frac{n^2}{n^3+3} < \frac{n^2}{n^3} = \frac1n < \frac\varepsilon2$$

Comment: Generally I am used to taking for $n>n_0=\nu=\max\{\left[\frac 2\varepsilon\right],1\}$. Upvote all your answers.